# How do I specify random effects using gamm models in R?

Tags: r, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

I am using GAMM models in the `mgcv` package to analyze how specific diversity measures (eg. Shannon) vary over time and with environmental variables (eg. temperature).

I have the initial model so far to analyze the time series:

```
modf<-gamm(y~ as.factor(year) + s(doy,bs='cc',k=kdy),method=mth,correlation=tcor,data=d,
           control=ctrl,random=NULL,gamma=1)
```

I want to include temperature as a random effect and thought of doing something like:

```
modf<-gamm(y~ as.factor(year) + s(doy,bs='cc',k=kdy), + s(temp,bs="re"),method=mth,
           correlation=tcor,data=d,control=ctrl,gamma=1)
```

However, so far I have only seen this for `gam` not `gamm`. Does it still work this way?

An example of type of data structure:

```
$ total_abundance: num  6364161 1929775 7057036 1266342 3981198 ...
$ shannon        : num  1.87 2.08 1.95 1.84 2.06 ...
$ turnover       : num  0.613 0.475 0.525 0.556 0.429 ...
$ year           : int  1985 1986 1987 1987 1987 1988 1989 1989 1991 
$ month          : int  8 12 3 7 8 5 1 8 1 9 ...
$ day            : int  20 8 15 6 17 9 16 29 14 4 ...
$ temp           : num  25.5 9.87 4.8 19.72 26.03 ...
$ doy            : num  232 342 74 187 229 130 16 241 14 247 ...
```

where doy is 'day of year' and accounts for seasonality.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "add in temperature as random effect"? Is `temp` a continuous variable or something else? What is the grouping structure you have in mind? Might I suggest including some sample data in your question -- you are more likely to get a helpful answer that way.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be wanting to do doesn't make any sense unless you want the linear effect of `temp` to vary within the levels of a grouping factor.

Typically, you specify this random slope using `random` as

```
list(group = ~ x)
```

where `group` is a factor grouping variable and `x` is your `temp`.

What you are asking for with `temp = ~ 1` is a random intercept for the unique values of `temp`, which is probably asking too much of the data.

The equivalent of `s(time, bs = "re")` requires you to remove the intercept from the `random` formula:

```
 list(group = ~ x - 1)
```

but you still need a `group` variable.

If you just want to control for `temp`, add it as a linear parametric effect (`+ temp`) or a smooth effect (`+ s(temp)`) in the `gamm()` model formula.

Comment: No I don't want to control for temp I want to see how diversity changes with temperature as well as time. It would need to be a random effect though.

Comment: Controlling for `temp` is the same thing as `see[ing] how diversity changes with temperature...`. If you want it to be a random effect, please explain what you mean by this? You don't appear to have a grouping variable within which to have separate effects of `temp`. A random effect of `temp`, a continuous variable, necessarily entails estimating a value for the slope (effect) of `temp` in each level of a grouping variable. What is your grouping variable?

Comment: Who said `s(temp, bs = "re")` was doing anything sensible with your data? It is most certainly *not* doing what you think it is doing. You are getting a single effect of `temp`, the estimated value of which will equal the parametric fixed effects coefficient if you include it in the model as `temp`. (Try it!) This most certainly is not a random effect in any typical sense of the word.

Comment: I thought that temperature covaries with time that's why I thought it would be a random variable. Is there no way of specifying it without a grouping factor? Or should I just give up with the gamm and calculate it another way..

Comment: What do you mean by a "random variable"? Note that a `random variable` is *not* the same thing as a "random effect". Do you want the effects of `temp` and `time` on `diversity` to interact? Or do you just want to estimate the effect of `temp` on `diversity` as well as the `time` effect? At the moment, what you are asking is unclear because the terminology you are using is confusing and non-standard.

Comment: Sorry yes I meant random effect. I am only a student so I am not so well-versed in the terminology. If I just want to estimate the effect of temp effect and time effect on diversity I would just add that in as another smooth or linear parametric effect? But if there was an interaction between time and temp could I specify that in the model

Comment: It would be helpful if you don't argue with me about this stuff then! My answer shows how to do the linear or smooth effect for `temp`. If you want an interaction then you need to replace the `year` and `time` terms and just use `te(year, time)`, which includes the marginal smooths (main effects) and a smooth interaction of the two covariates. There are ways to decompose the `te()` smooth into marginal effects and an interaction  (see `?ti`) if you want but `te()` should suffice unless you want to test for an interaction over and above the two marginal smooth effects.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. I will use either the linear or smooth effect initially then and maybe after I could put all my sites together and use that as the grouping variable in the random effects model.